# looking for file location insert/update inventory_stock table for products

Tags: magento2.4, category-products, multi-source-inventory, salable, msi-source

I am looking for code where it insert/update is_salable  column in `inventory_stock_1,inventory_stock_2` table anyone know from which file it is updating this data?
when I save product in admin it inserting/updating this tables according to product stock

here is my table
[image]